# VBA Scripts to find duplicates using special conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database with a lot of records and each record has 5 fields namely INVOICE NUMBER, DATE, AMOUNT, SHIPMENT NUMBER and QUANTITY.

How do i write a VBA script that searches for duplicates. The way to searching duplicates is that if any three fields of the record match then the record is highlighted in a separate colour. The fields that are suppose to be matched are not specified, they can be any three fields.

For example, if INVOICE NUMBER, SHIPMENT NUMBER and QUANTITY match in some records then its shown as duplicates and highlighted. Similarly if INVOICE NUMBER, QUANTITY and DATE matches in a few records then they are listed as duplicates as well.

So in the database, out of the 5 fields if any 3 match then they are listed as duplicates and highlighted in a different colour.

Can anyone please help me write a VBA script that does that?

Comment: Are you sure that is what you want? If any 3 columns match, then call it a duplicate? I would be fearful that you would falsely identify matches that have the same Date,Amount, and Quantity, but are seperate orders. Shouldn't your shipment Number or Invoice number be unique enough to group orders by?

Comment: Alright, here is the deal. I have an existing database of records. Each recored has the fields Invoice Number, Vendor Code, Currency, Amount and Date. My job is to extract new data records from the SAP System and add them to the database. Now, when i add records i need to check if any three fields match between the existing database and the new records. When i add them on my excel sheet, i have to make sure that no 3 fields of the new records match with the existing ones. If any there do then i highlight them as duplicates.

Comment: Suppose i need to add 3 records today with the same fields Invoice Number, Vendor Code, Currency, Amount and Date. Suppose for the first record Vendor Code, Invoice Number and Amount match with any record in the excel file then its highlighted as a duplicate and i forward it to be checked. For the next record suppose Vendor Code, Amount and Currency match then it shows as a potential duplicate as well and is highlighted and i forward it again to be checked before the final payments are made.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an easy way to do this.  With five fields, there are 10 possible ways that any 3 of those fields can be evaluated.  So, you could create a macro that basically cycles through all of the columns, searching for duplicates, but it won't be very easy.

I have done something like this in the past, but relied instead on a formula in a cell to do the work.  I used the SUMPRODUCT function to look up values.  Here is what it would look like for you.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A3)*(B$2:B2=B3)*(C$2:C2=C3)) + SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A3)*(B$2:B2=B3)*(D$2:D2=D3)) + + SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A3)*(B$2:B2=B3)*(E$2:E2=E3)) + SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A3)*(C$2:C2=C3)*(D$2:D2=D3)) + SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A3)*(C$2:C2=C3)*(E$2:E2=E3)) + SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A3)*(D$2:D2=D3)*(E$2:E2=E3)) + SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B2=B3)*(C$2:C2=C3)*(D$2:D2=D3)) + SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B2=B3)*(C$2:C2=C3)*(E$2:E2=E3)) + SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B2=B3)*(D$2:D2=D3)*(E$2:E2=E3)) + SUMPRODUCT((C$2:C2=C3)*(D$2:D2=D3)*(E$2:E2=E3))
```

Note that this assumes that your 5 fields are in columns A to E, and never change.  The above formula is also designed to be put in row 2 of whatever column you want it in.  Then just copy down the formula to have it auto-adjust values for the current row.  Row 2 doesn't need it, since that should be your first record (assuming there are headers of course).

Oh, since I didn't mention it, if this formula returns a 1, then that indicates duplicate data.  A 0 indicates that it is unique (so far).

Here is some psuedocode to assist with creating a macro.

```
For each row from 2 to currentRow - 1
   Dim numMatches as integer
   numMatches = 0
   if activeSheet.Range("A" & row) = activeSheet.Range("A" & currentRow) then
      nuMatches = numMatches + 1
   Endif
   'do the above if statement for each compare
   if numMatches >= 3 then
      'format the currentRow to indicate duplicate
   endif
Next Row
```

Comment: didnt get the entire formula...Could you please type that again?

Comment: I will give it a shot, i was told to design a Macro that does this, lol. Its not going ot be easy i have to find another to do it. I will give your idea a go, thanks for your help. Much Appreciated.

Comment: To get the entire formula, click at the beginning, scroll right, then hold Shift and click on the right of the last close paren.

Comment: I have also added some psuedocode above for a macro solution.  You should be able to create a macro using that logic and a little tweaking.  I am not near Excel right now for specific language...

Comment: How can i notify you if i wanted to ask you something more after a couple of days? Would it be totally inappropriate to ask for your mail?

Comment: Just post it here and I will see it.

Comment: Hello, how is it going??

Comment: Thanks, the formula that you gave works perfectly. Now i have a database of 5 fields from columns A through E. In the column G i have the duplicate field, so as and when the duplicates occur the numbers in G are incremented. I want to ask you if there is a way to highlight the ROWS that have these duplicates...? I am getting the numbers indicating how many times duplicates happen but how do i highlight the rows that have those duplicates. It would be great if you gave me some ideas about this, much appreciated. Cheers !!

Comment: Something like this would also be useful. Instead of the numbers, if it shows a word "duplicate" next to the rows that are duplicates. Counting the increment is not the exact requirement here, all i have to do is to highlight the rows that are duplicates. Would that be possible?

Comment: Check out conditional formatting.  You could also wrap that formula in an if statement to get the word 'duplicate' (e.g. if(formula > 0, 'dupe','not dupe')

Comment: Does that require me to change the existing formula?

Comment: Yes, but it is a minor one.  =if(currentFormula > 0,'dupe','not dupe')

Comment: Thank you very much. i used this

Comment: I used this =IF(G3>0,"DUPLICATE","NOT DUPLICATE"). Its printing DUPLICATE or NOT DUPLICATE in a separate row. Now all i need is to highlight it with a different color.

Comment: Just look up "conditional formatting".  This is a fairly simple conditional, and it will most likely do what you want it to.

Comment: Yeah did that, it works alright. I just wanted to scratch your head more. Now that i have the duplicate row in a separate color, i wanted to know if i could color the individual cells that are duplicates. For example record no 200 is a duplicate of record number 11 and 3 fields Vendor_Id, Amount, Invoice_No are the duplicates fields in both these records. Is there a way of coloring these fields that are duplicates?

Comment: Wow.  The only way I can think to do that off the top of my head is to split out the formula into the 10 different options and then do conditional formatting based on those results.  That is a lot of work though.

Comment: So, split the formula where there are plus signs, so your first one would be =SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A3)*(B$2:B2=B3)*(C$2:C2=C3)).  If that one comes back true, then columns A, b and C are the duplicates, and you can highlight them. However, note that if there are 4 duplicate fields, then this will probably not help highlighting the 4th.  Not sure how you would deal with that.